# Execute backup script when USB disk is mounted

Tags: systemd

I have a USB drive that gets automatically decrypted and mounted when I plug it. Then, once it is mounted, I execute a backup script to rsync the local FS to that disk. And then I eject the drive.

I would like to automate this so that when I plug the drive, it gets decrypted and mounted, the script gets executed, and the drive gets unmounted / ejected. (If I can get a notification when it finishes, it's even better, but optional.)

So I have tried with systemd, but I am open to other solutions (although now that I have spent time fighting with systemd, I would really like to understand how that works).

For the moment I have tried to create a service that depends on the mount of the USB drive. But the service fails to activate complaining the mount does not exist when the drive is not plugged.

So then I tried to create a path unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitors the backup path availability

[Path]
PathExists=/run/media/user/backup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the path becomes available then it launches the corresponding service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rsync System Backup
Requires=usb-hd-backup.path

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -aAXS --info=progress2 --delete --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /run/media/user/backup


[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

That works the first time. But then when I unmount the drive, the path remains (that does not happen when I launch the script manually). So the next time I plug the drive, it gets decrypted and, since the original path already exists, it gets mounted to a different path (the same as the original with a '1' appended at the end). So the scripts executes to a path that does not lead to the drive (and fails since the /run mount is very small).

I think there are some ideas of systemd that I don't really grasp here.

Comment: Do you mount the Partition over udev?

Comment: @Bahamut it is mounted automatically. How can I check?

Comment: It's okay, I tought you create an own udev-rule.  So its mountet over udisks2. The Problem is I think, that when you backup your system it is as  root. So the Mountpoint /media/user/hd belongs to root, and udisks2 can not erase it after umounting your hd. So it stays.  and udisks2 create a new one with the suffix 1.

Comment: can we meet us in chat <http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50258/http-unix-stackexchange-com-questions-331205-execute-backup-script-when-usb-dis  Maybe I had an Idee